# Java batch doesn't execute well .bat file that execute php app

Tags: java, php, daemon

I have a weird issue. I created a PHP App that reads files and then, move to another directory. The app works fine when i run it.

Now, i created a daemon on java that runs a .bat file that runs my php script.

My .bat is this "invoker.bat":

```
cd C:\xampp\php
PHP C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\ler.php
exit
```

My daemon on java is this:

```
package edidemon;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

/**
 *
 * @author Bottago SA
 */
public class EDIDemon extends Observable {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EDIDemon edid = new EDIDemon();
        edid.addObserver(new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
                //se invoca por medio de cmd al php lector EDI
                try {
                    String cmd = "invoker.bat";
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public EDIDemon() {
        Timer timer;
        timer = new Timer(12000, new ActionListener()//6000 es un segundo
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(new Date());
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Part of my php code that reads the file and moves it.

```
if ($handle = scandir('C:/xampp/htdocs/EDI/Prepared')){

    foreach($handle as $entry){
        if (in_array($entry, array(".",".."))) continue;
        if(isset($entry)){      
          echo "<table><tr><td><strong>File: ".$entry."</strong></td></tr></table><br>";
          //---Mover archivos de un directorio a otro almacenados una vez leidos
          $subir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EDI/Prepared/';
          $path = $subir.$entry;
          $Uploaded = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EDI/Uploaded/';
          $Failed = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EDI/Failed/';

        $newName = file($path);
        $ponteiro = fopen ($path,"r");
        $arquivo = '';

        while (!feof ($ponteiro)) {
            $arquivo = $arquivo.fgets($ponteiro);
        }           
        fclose ($ponteiro);

        $padrao = fnc_resgata_padrao($arquivo);
        $segmento = fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($arquivo, "UNB");
        $sender = fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,2,0);
        $sendername = substr($sender, 0, 3);

        if ($padrao == "COARRI" && $sendername !== "TPG"){
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri(trim($arquivo));
            prc_mostra_coarri($a, $entry, $arquivo);
            copy($path, $Uploaded.$entry);
            unlink($path);              

        }
        elseif ($padrao == "COARRI" && $sendername == "TPG"){
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri_header_tpg(trim($arquivo));
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri_tpg(trim($arquivo)) +$a;
            prc_mostra_coarri($a, $entry, $arquivo);
            copy($path, $Uploaded.$entry);
            unlink($path);              
        }
        elseif ($padrao == "CODECO") {
            $a = fnc_processa_codeco(trim($arquivo));
            prc_mostra_codeco($a, $entry, $arquivo);
            copy($path, $Uploaded.$entry);
            unlink($path);              
        }
        elseif ($padrao == "BAPLIE") {              
            $a = fnc_processa_baplie(trim($arquivo));                                 
            prc_mostra_baplie($a);              
        }
        elseif ($padrao == "WESTIM"){
            $a = fnc_processa_westim(trim($arquivo));
            prc_mostra_westim($a, $entry, $arquivo);
        }
        else {
            copy($path, $Failed.$entry);
            unlink($path);
            echo "<table><tr><td><strong>Archivo incorrecto</strong></td></tr></table>";
        }           
       } else {
        echo "You need to select a file.  Please try again.";
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is, if i just run the .bat, the files that the php app read moves to another directory as usual. But, if i run the daemon (java app), it only read the file, insert on the DB but doesn't move to another directory.

¿Can anyone have a clue?

Comment: Hum you probably should post the php code if the php somehow fails when "run" by java

Comment: @RC. I just added the php code.